# How to adjust nav bar height on a device which is an ipad

Tags: ios, swift, device

I have tried adjusting the nav bar height and width using the following code below it is working when the device is an iphone but it does not work when the device is ipad.

code on detecting the device.

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
}else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
}
```

code.

```
let height = CGFloat(60)
            navbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
```

Comment: you could just use a view instead of a nav bar...

Comment: what type of view you mean Sir?

Comment: Just a view with the background color of your choice and a title (You are mimicking a nav bar). And you can make the background color of the real nav bar transparent so that you can still see the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the height of navigation bar. Some workarounds may work, but they can break any time with new versions of iOS or Xcode.

You can gain a bit more space by setting `self.navigationItem.prompt` (where `self` is a view controller) to a non-empty value, but that's about it.

There is also the option of creating your own navigation bar, which is fairly complicated.

Comment: but it did work on a iphone device the nav bar height is changing depending on the assigned height value

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck That's what I meant by "some workarounds may work". There is no official way to do this.

Comment: am i right Sir ? but using the following code width is actually working except the height